# Replace sub strings in string using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a string like this

```
var str = "sin(30)+sin(40)-sin(50)+cos(10)/sin(20)";
```

The string format may change.

What I need is that I have to change all `sin` value with `temp`

The result should be like this

**temp+temp-temp+cos(10)/temp**

What I tried:

```
if (str.indexOf("sin") >= 0){
  var find = "sin(.*)";
  var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');
  res = str.replace(re, "temp");
}
```

But this not give the solution. The variable `find` I used is not correct. I need your help. Please give 
me a solution. I using **jQuery**.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a non-greedy version of `.*`, which you make by adding a `?`

You can just match `sin\(.*?\)` and replace it with `temp`. Note that `(` and `)` has to be escape, using a backslash.

```
var str = "sin(30)+sin(40)-sin(50)+cos(10)/sin(20)";
str = str.replace(/sin\(.*?\)/g,"temp");
console.log(str);
```

Comment: one doubt buddy, How can I get something like this: temp(30)+temp(40)-temp(50)+cos(10)/temp(20)

Answer (score 0):

Use Regex like:

```
var find = "sin\\(\\d+\\)";
```

As .* is greedy in nature,

Comment: one doubt buddy, How can I get something like this: temp(30)+temp(40)-temp(50)+cos(10)/temp(20)

Comment: Just set find as sin nothing else.